# Convert Currency with multiple string (£20 5s) to Float

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with some Currency in the following format: £20 5s (20 Pounds and 5 shillings -> 20 shillings = 1 pound)

Now i should convert it to a float (£20 5s == 20.25) to calculate the mean in this Dataframe. But I have no idea how I should do it with pandas, for example which function of pandas i should use?

Comment: I doubt there's a built in function for that ... so `df.apply(your_function)`

Comment: Half a century -- that's how long ago Britain went decimal.  Even before that, you wouldn't normally see it written that way.  It would be something like £20/5/-.  Where did you get this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'currency': ['£20 5s', '£30 3s', '£10 1s']})
df['currency'] = df['currency'].str.replace('£', '').str.replace('s', '')
df['currency'] = df['currency'].str.split().apply(lambda x: float(x[0]) + float(x[1]) / 20)
print(df)

# currency
# 0     20.25
# 1     30.15
# 2     10.05
```